# SoundCloud Stream URL 404

Tags: javascript, ruby, api, soundcloud, soundmanager2

I'm trying to stream a track from soundcloud using their Javascript SDK, but I keep getting a 404 when asking for the stream url.

I tried multiple ways including:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  SC.initialize({
    client_id: "CLIENT_ID",
  });
  playTrack();
});

var playTrack = function() {

  SC.stream("/i1/tracks/137078163", function(sound) {
    sound.play();
  });
}
```

which returns a 404.

```
client = Soundcloud.new(:client_id => 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID')
track = client.get('/tracks/293')
stream_url = client.get(track.stream_url, :allow_redirects => true)
```

also returns a 404.

The only way I got it to work was using a different stream url on SO, but I'd like to know why using their JS SDK doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your JS example, whats that for an endpoint /i1/tracks/137078163 ?

When i use the track-id from your ruby example, in your JS slightly changed, its working.

So i'd say your track-id is wrong in your js ex.

Pls. check.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

SC.initialize({client_id: "679877a8ddb9badc6a2a75373c5f3de7",});

var playTrack = function() 
{ SC.stream("/tracks/293", function(sound) { sound.play();});}   

playTrack();
});
```

Working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/iambnz/Y5Y25/

Comment: I realized that it won't work for non-streamable tracks :) As far as that endpoint goes, I found an example on SO that had an alternative endpoint to get a stream url if the main one didn't work. The i1 is not necessary but basically that API call from the JS is something like `/.../tracks/293/stream?client_id=` And the alternative endpoint that I got to work was `/.../tracks/293/streams?client_id=` **(streams with an s)** I had to modify the JS but anyways... I see the issue and thanks for the help!